# Invalid hook call with useCallback in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem, I tried to transform in a class this function from this example :
https://codesandbox.io/s/5vn3lvz2n4

But, I got an error. Here is the code :

```
import React, { Component, useCallback } from "react";
import Gallery from "react-photo-gallery";
import Carousel, { Modal, ModalGateway } from "react-images";

class Gallerie extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      currentImage: 0,
      setCurrentImage: 0,
      viewerIsOpen: false,
      setViewerIsOpen: false,
    }   
}

  render(){
    const openLightbox = useCallback((event, { photo, index }) => {
      this.state.setCurrentImage(index);
      this.state.setViewerIsOpen(true);
    }, []);

    const closeLightbox = () => {
      this.state.setCurrentImage(0);
      this.state.setViewerIsOpen(false);
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Gallery photos={this.props.photos} onClick={() => openLightbox} />
        <ModalGateway>
          {this.state.viewerIsOpen ? (
            <Modal onClose={() =>closeLightbox}>
              <Carousel
                currentIndex={this.state.currentImage}
                views={this.props.photos.map(x => ({
                  ...x,
                  srcset: x.srcSet,
                  caption: x.title
                }))}
              />
            </Modal>
          ) : null}
        </ModalGateway>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Gallerie;
```

Here is the problem and what I got :

[image]

I don't exaclty know what the useCallBack does. If I just copy / paste the example, it works. The problem is that the variable "photos" is used as props cause it will be different for each user. So I need it into other components. If I use a function like the example, I can't use props...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a `hook` inside a `class` based `component`. First convert it to a functional component

```
const Gallerie = props =>{
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        currentImage: 0,
        setCurrentImage: 0,
        viewerIsOpen: false,
        setViewerIsOpen: false,
    })

    const openLightbox = useCallback((event, { photo, index }) => {
        setState({...state, setCurrentImage: index, setViewerIsOpen: true});
    }, []);

    const closeLightbox = () => {
        setState({...state, setCurrentImage: 0,setViewerIsOpen: false })
    };

    return (
        <div>
          <Gallery photos={props.photos} onClick={() => openLightbox} />
          <ModalGateway>
            {state.viewerIsOpen ? (
              <Modal onClose={() =>closeLightbox}>
                <Carousel
                  currentIndex={state.currentImage}
                  views={props.photos.map(x => ({
                    ...x,
                    srcset: x.srcSet,
                    caption: x.title
                  }))}
                />
              </Modal>
            ) : null}
          </ModalGateway>
        </div>
      );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I then export it to use it into the main component?

Comment: Exactly how you do with class components. `export default Gallerie`

Comment: With copy/paste of your code + export default, I have exaclty the same error message...

Comment: You are updating the state incorrectly and I've missed that! Update the answer. Try now